# Replace more than 150000 character with sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I want to replace this LONG string with `sed`
And I got the string from `grep` which I store it into variable `var`
Here is my `grep` command and my `var` variable :

```
var=$(grep -P -o "[^:]//.{0,}" /home/lazuardi/project/assets/static/admin/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css.map | grep -P -o "//.{0,})
```

Here is the output from grep : [string](http://pastebin.com/Eq9kKi5U)

Then I try to replace it with `sed` command

```
sed -i "s|$var||g" /home/lazuardi/project/assets/static/admin/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css.map
```

But it give me output `bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long`

How can I replace it?

NB : That string has 183544 character in one line.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Also: what is the result of `getconf ARG_MAX` ?

Comment: You can try saving the sed command into a temporary file and let sed read it.

Comment: @rici Linux Mint 17.1 and `getconf ARG_MAX` output is 2097152.

Comment: @LazuardiNPutra: Right, the command line is nowhere near 2M. You must have a bunch of exported variables. Try this: `declare -px | wc -c`. That will tell you roughly how much space your exported variables are using.

Comment: @rici `declare -px | wc -c` output is 3975. what was that number stand for? is that for length of my variable?

Comment: @LazuardiNPutra: `declare -px` prints out (-p) all your exported variables (-x), and `wc -c` tells you how many bytes it read. 3975 is about right, so I have no idea where your memory vanished. Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm still stuck here :( I try to `echo $var | wc -w` it give me 16870. How long does maximum limit arguments that sed can handle?

Comment: you can find out how long a variable is by using echo ${#var}. wc -w tells you how many (whitespace-separated) words there are, which is not a very useful measurement.

Comment: Also `echo $var` without quotes will squish whitespace, including newlines.  You want `echo "$var" | wc` if you want any kind of useful counts (where the double quotes around `"$var"` is the beef; `wc` is obviously just a quick way to get some numbers).

Comment: why do you use several grep giving a huge string to ctach in a variable and than reuse a sed to change it when you can directly select it in sed or awk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you *actually* trying to accomplish here?  `sed` is line-oriented, so you cannot replace a multi-line string (not even if you replace literal newlines with `\n` .... Well, there are ways to write a `sed` script which effectively replaces a sequence of lines, but it gets tortured quickly).

```
bash$ var=$(head -n 2 /etc/mtab)

bash$ sed "s|$var||" /etc/mtab
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command

bash$ sed "s|${var//$'\n'/\\n}||" /etc/mtab | diff -u /etc/mtab -

bash$ # (didn't replace anything, so no output)
```

As a workaround, what you *probably* want could be approached by replacing the newlines in `$var` with `\|` (or possibly just `|`, depending on your `sed` dialect) similarly to what was demonstrated above, but you'd still be bumping into the `ARG_MAX` limit and have a bunch of other pesky wrinkles to iron out, so let's not go there.

However, what you are attempting can be magnificently completed by `sed` itself, all on its own.  You don't need a list of the strings; after all, `sed` too can handle regular expressions (and nothing in the regex you are using actually requires Perl extensions, so the `-P` option is by and large superfluous).

```
sed -i 's%\([^:]\)//.*%\1%' file
```

There is a minor caveat -- if there are strings which occur both with and without `:` in front, your original command would have replaced them all (if it had worked), whereas this one will only replace the occurrences which do not have a colon in front.  That means comments at beginning of line will not be touched -- if you want them removed too, just add a line anchor as an alternative; `sed -i 's%\(^\|[^:]\)//.*%\1%' file`

If you want the comments in `var` for other reasons, the `grep` can be cleaned up significantly, too.  (Obviously, you'd run this before performing the replacement.)

```
var=$(grep -P -o '[^:]\K//.*' file)
```

(The `\K` extension is one which genuinely requires `-P`.  And of course, the common, clear, standard, readable, portable, obvious, simple way to write `{0,}` is `*`.)

Comment: BIG THANKS!!!!!!! You really solve my problem with this `sed -i 's%\([^:]\)//.*%\1%' file` !!!!!! Thank you so much !! Sorry, I'm too happy :D

Comment: Its probably safer to use a non-printable character like SOH instead of a pipe (`NL_TOKEN=$(echo -en "\001")`). I have tried using sed on very large files in the past and although I haven't looked at the source code, I think it is safe to say that sed was not designed to handle huge input files. If you really need to process large files on a regular basis you probably would be better off splitting them up if you can and processing them piece by piece or use a different tool.

Comment: If you are using Bash, `$'\001'` would be more elegant than `$(echo -en "\001")`. But like I wrote in the answer, I don't recommend using `sed` like this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

On most systems these days, the value of `ARG_MAX` is big enough to handle 150k without problems, but it is important to note that while the limit is called `ARG_MAX` and the error message indicates that the command line is too long, the real limit is the sum of the sizes of the arguments and all (exported) environment variables. Also, Linux imposes a limit of 128k (131,072 bytes) for a single argument string. Exceeding any of these limits triggers an error return of `E2BIG`, which is printed as "Argument list too long".

In any case, bash built-ins are exempt from the limit, so you should be able to feed the command into sed as a command file:

```
echo "s|$var||g" | sed -f - -i /home/lazuardi/project/assets/static/admin/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css.map
```

That may not help you much, though. Your variable is full of regex metacharacters, so it will not match the string itself. You'll need to clean it up in order to be able to use it as a regular expression.
There's probably a cleaner way to do that edit, though.

Comment: it give me output like this `sed: file - line 2: Invalid preceding regular expression` . I thought my variable is too long to be handled by sed :(

Comment: @LazuardiNPutra: That's a different problem; it is the result of that string containing regular expression metacharacters. You are really trying to remove exact characters, not strings which match a regex.

Comment: Aahhh I see I see, let me try it first. Thanks you :)

Comment: Great sleuthing. However, I cant get the `-f -` approach to work (GNU sed 4.2.2, Ubuntu 14.04): `echo 's|a||g' | sed -f - <<<'abc'` prints nothing (it seems that stdin is ignored altogether); by contrast, if I use a process substitution, things work as expected:  `sed -f <(echo 's|a||g') <<<'abc'`.

Comment: @mklement0: You'd find that `-f -` works fine if you don't try to both pipe and redirect stdin with a herestring. I think the pipe wins. Try `echo 's|a||g' | sed -f - <(echo abc)`, for example

Comment: @rici: Oops! But they _look_ so different, how can they both be stdin? (Just kidding.) Thanks for clearing that up. As an aside: BSD `sed` doesn't accept `-` with `-f`, and OSX doesn't have the single-argument length limit, though `ARG_MAX` is surprisingly low at 256k (as of OSX 10.10.2).

Comment: @mklement0: Annoying that BSD sed doesn't treat the - as stdin; Posix is vague on the point, so I guess I can't complain, but still... Old versions of Linux had an even smaller ARG_MAX, iirc -- I think it was the 128k which is now the single-argument limit. I don't believe that Posix contemplates a single-argument limit, but it only requires ARG_MAX to be 4096 or greater. (My exported environment exceeds that (kubuntu).)

Comment: Incidentally, a (very old, by now) list of the limit on some systems is at http://porkmail.org/era/unix/arg-max.html -- indeed, this shows Linux 2.0.33 with 128k.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link, @tripleee. http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ is more recent (though also not current) and covers Linux up to 2.6.23; it does show that the 2.6.23 was the first version _not_ to have the 128k limit anymore.